# Convergence of series defined on half space

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let E be an arbitrary ellipse in $\mathbb{R}^2$ with boundary $\partial G$. We denote by $E_T$ the dilated ellipse
$$
\{ Tx:x \in E \}.
$$
Furthermore, let $\tau(x)$ be the unit outward normal vector of $E$ at $x\in \partial G$.

We assume that the sum
$$
\sum_{k\in \mathbb{Z}^2 : k\cdot \tau(x)<0}f(k)
$$
is equal to A. [$\cdot$ is the standard scalar product]

I would like to proof that
$$
\lim_{T \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{ k\in \mathbb{Z}^2 : k\in E_T-Tx} f(k)=A.
$$

Can anyone help me find an approach or give a reference to literature for these kinds of problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition, requiring that the sum :
$$\sum_{k\in \mathbb{Z}^2 : k\cdot \tau(x)<0}f(k)$$
converges to $A$ means that for any non-decreasing sequence of finite subsets $X_n \subset \{k\in \mathbb{Z}^2 : k\cdot \tau(x)<0\}$, we have :
$$\lim_{n\to +\infty} \sum_{k\in X_n} f(k) = A$$

Therefore, we just have to check that
$\{k\in\mathbb Z^2 |k\in E_T - Tx\} $ is a finite subset of $ \{ k\in\mathbb Z^2 |k\cdot \tau(x) < 0\}$
and that :
$$\bigcup_{T\to \infty} \{k\in\mathbb Z^2 |k\in E_T - Tx\} = \{ k\in\mathbb Z^2 |k\cdot \tau(x) < 0\}$$

It is easy to see that this is true.

Comment: Thank you very much! Do you know of a book/paper that discusses your definition of convergence?

Comment: This is basically Lebesgue integration using the counting measure.